# Advisable to install a service check valve in front of a thermal expansion tank

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a thermal expansion tank and the maker (Watts) recommends installing a service check valve between the tank and the pipe.

While I understand the convenience factor of the SCV, my concern is that I would be introducing another potential point of failure into the system by adding a service check valve. Is it advisable to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is good practice to fit an isolation valve.

This makes replacement of the expansion tank easy without draining the whole system.

This is also a practice followed for many components in a water system, as these valves are cheap & reliable, so putting them either side of a pump can save a lot of hassle when trying to bleed a system.

Comment: Hi, Mike. Sounds like a good answer, but would you mind adding a bit of context, or just a few more sentences of support? We don't usually like sentence-fragment answers. (Thanks.)